# How to associate deeply nested forms properly in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, associations

I've been watching Ryan's screencast:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

I have a similar but different problem, and am hoping someone can help.

---

I have the following four models that are required (at minimum) to register:

- **Account**
- **Company**
- **Address**
- **User**

At registration, I'd like for **Company**, **Address**, and **User** to individually be associated with **Account** directly.

Also, I would like te **User** to be associate with the **Company**, and the **Address** to be associated with the **Company**.

*Note: Each has a foreign key: **`account_id`** -- This is essentially a multi-tenant system with a single database.*

---

My associates are currently setup as follows:

**Account**

has_many :companies

has_many :users

has_many :addresses

(In the future, other models will use the Company and the Address model, that is why Account has many of those)

**User**

belongs_to :account

belongs_to :company

**Company**

belongs_to :account

has_many :users

has_many :addresses

**Address**

belongs_to :account

belongs_to :company

---

I've been using **`accepts_nested_attributes_for`** method in the models, and the **`fields_for`** method in the views, but have only been able to get things associated in a purely nested way.

In other words, a **User** *gets* associate to a **Company**, *but is not* associated to an **Account**.

I need for **each of the models** to be associated with the **Account**. (Except for Account itself of course)

Is there a way to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you confuse some where.

- Account Has Many Companies
- Company Has Many Users
- Company belongs to account
- account User belongs_to company
- user belongs_to account either through company  or create account_id in user

In views you can create form company and then create fields_for for account and inside account create fields_for user.

I think this will solve your purpose.
don't forget to add accept_nesetd_attributes inside company and account

Comment: I clarified the the question.  Would you mind taking another look?

Comment: May be you can run after_create callback on user and being associated with account from finding account from company.mean while i will look into other solution if i found.

Comment: Thanks.  I was thinking there was some built in Rails magic to handle a case like this, but I now think there is not.  So I'm just handling the rest of the associations by passing the account object into the account model for finalization immediately after save.